# How to Include buttons in email template with dynamic Link

Tags: apex, email

I am sending sample survey email to users whenever accounts meets particular criteria.

I created a apex class and iam accessing contacts and sending contact details to below SendEmail method.Now i am attaching a link within email template through HTML body but i dont want to send long link to the user.

Is there any way to hyperlink above link to small text or clickable image.

Like Below:

> Site_Details+'&cId='+Contactdetails+'&caId='+CaseId;

My code looks like:

```
public Static void sendMail(Id accountdetails,String Emaildetails,Id Contactdetails,Id CaseId,String Customername,String Accountsname)
    {
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        sendTo.add(Emaildetails);
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        mail.setReplyTo('pavank@azuga.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Azuga Telematics');
        mail.setsubject('Invitation to participate in survey');
        String body = 'Hi '+Customername+','+'<br/>'+'<br/>';
        body += 'Account Name:'+'<br/>'+'<br/>';
        body += Label.Churn_Site_Details+'&cId='+Contactdetails+'&caId='+CaseId;
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(
                                 new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        inspectResults(results,accountdetails);
    }
```

As per @James i had updated my code:

```
body += '<a href="+Label.Churn_Site_Details+'&cId='+Contactdetails+'&ca‌Id='+CaseId+">
  <img border="0" alt="Link" src="https://cs72.salesforce.com/0155D0000004ryk" width="100" 
    height="100"></a>';
```

> Expression cannot be assigned

Answer (score 2):

You could use a href. This should work:

```
body += '<a href="'+Label.Churn_Site_Details+'&cId='+Contactdetails+'&caId='+CaseId+">Link to Record</a>'
```

Comment: Any Posibility href to button click Or image

Comment: You could replace the link text with an image:
`body += '<a href="'+Label.Churn_Site_Details+'&cId='+Contactdetails+'&caId='+CaseId+"><img border="0" alt="Link" src="http://imageurl.gif" width="100" height="100"></a>'`

Comment: Thanks is there any way to reference images from docs in abovde link

Comment: Yes you can, just open the document, and copy the image url. Just make sure that it's externally available.

Comment: I got an error like Expression cannot be assigned will you please check i updated my question

Comment: make sure that you put it all in one line:

`body += '<a href="'+Label.Churn_Site_Details+'&cId='+Contactdetails+'&ca‌Id='+CaseId+'"><img border="0" alt="Link" src="https://cs72.salesforce.com/0155D0000004ryk" width="100"  height="100"></a>';`

also you should have used the image url instead of the document url