# Email Customer 'Verified' Button

Tags: email, button

I want to have customers verify their shipping address. 
To do this, I want to be able to send them a button in an email that says "Verify my Address".

 When This button is clicked by the customer, I want it to update the "Address Verified" checkbox in the Assessment object to true.

Is this possible? I'm not even sure where to start here. I do have the email template in place, just not sure how to work the button.

My current code in Email Template:
```

```
<button onclick="setVerifiedTrue()">Click to Confirm Correct Address</button>

function setVerifiedtrue() {
    {!Assessment__c.Shipping_Address_Verified__c}=='true';
};
```

Comment: Take a look at [Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview.htm&type=5)

Comment: I want an outside customer, without access to Salesforce, to be able to click a button within an email we send them to verify their address. It doesn't look like quick actions can do this?

Comment: You're right, I misread your question. Here's a better Q&A: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197644/how-to-include-buttons-in-email-template-with-dynamic-link